# Arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, errors

If I run this code:

```
select 99999 * 9999
```

result = 999890001

If I run this code:

```
select 9999923 * 99999999
```

result:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

And If I run the following code:

```
select 922337299987987689745893 * 999999994564
```

result = 922337294974162127011191918541325652

Why am I getting this arithmetic overflow error within a specific range?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rules that SQL Server uses to derive the type of literals are complex, with some odd behaviours that are maintained these days for backward compatibility. For example, the derived type may depend on whether simple parameterization is applied. There are other (undocumented) considerations as well.

With those caveats out of the way, the situation you face is one of the simpler ones. The untyped literals are typed as `integer` when they will fit in that data type. The data type of the result is as specified in [* (Multiply) (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms176019.aspx):

> Returns the data type of the argument with the higher precedence.
>   For more information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms190309.aspx).

The two data types are both `integer` (with obviously the same precedence), so the result is also typed as `integer`. When the result does not fit, an error may be thrown (depending on settings).

When one of the literals is explicitly typed using `CAST` or `CONVERT` as (for example) `bigint` (which has a higher precedence than `integer`) the result type will be `bigint`, and no error occurs.

The two larger constants in the question are typed as `numeric(24,0)` and `numeric(12,0)` respectively. The result of multiplying them is typed as `numeric(37,0)` in accordance with the rules for `e1 * e2` shown in [Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx):

```
Result precision: p1 + p2 + 1 = 24 + 12 + 1 = 37
Result scale: s1 + s2 = 0 + 0 = 0

Result type: numeric (37,0)
```

Answer (score 6):

In Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx), it is said that

> The precision and scale for any expression that is not decimal is the precision and scale defined for the data type of the expression.

Since yours inputs are considered as int, the result is supposed to be a int, meaning below 2 147 483 647. If it's bigger, it will indeed raise an error.

If you cast one of your inputs as another datatype such as bigint, it will not fail :

```
select 9999923 * cast(99999999 as bigint)
-- 999992290000077
```

Answer (score 4):

This is due the default datatype that each literal number is interpreted as being.

The numbers in the first two queries are being assigned the datatype of `INT`. The large number in the third query is being assigned a datatype of `NUMERIC(24, 0)` (`NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL` are synonyms).

To see this, you can use the [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx) function to get the *resulting* datatype details of the literals (** *Please note: SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY might not return the initial type chosen by SQL Server in all cases* ):

```sql
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(99999, 'BaseType') AS [TypeFor99999],
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9999, 'BaseType') AS [TypeFor9999],
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9999923, 'BaseType') AS [TypeFor9999923],
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(99999999, 'BaseType') AS [TypeFor99999999];
```

Returns:

```
int   int   int   int
```

And then:

```sql
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(922337299987987689745893, 'BaseType') AS [Type],
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(922337299987987689745893, 'Precision') AS [Precision],
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(922337299987987689745893, 'Scale') AS [Scale];
```

Returns:

```
numeric 24  0
```

And the full expression gives you:

```sql
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(922337299987987689745893 * 999999994564, 'BaseType') AS [Type],
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(922337299987987689745893 * 999999994564, 'Precision') AS [Precision],
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(922337299987987689745893 * 999999994564, 'Scale') AS [Scale];
```

Returns:

```
numeric 37  0
```

For the query getting the error, convert one to `BIGINT` via `CONVERT(BIGINT, 9999923)`. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, 9999923) * 99999999
```

Returns:

```
999992290000077
```